# New to Ubuntu and can't connect to wifi

Tags: wireless, mac

I'm pretty much brand new to using Ubuntu and for the life of me I can't figure out how to connect to my wifi network.

I have no idea what kind of information I should post. Browsing other similar questions has been confusing and hectic, and I have no idea what kind of information will be needed to fix this.

The computer itself is an iMac4,1

Answer (score 0):

On your keyboard press CTRL+ALT+T 
A terminal will apear
[image]

Now in that terminal insert the commands i give you one at a time, pressing enter afther each one.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

Afther the proces is finished type:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Afther the process is done, just log out and then back in and tell me if your wirless works

Comment: I have no idea how to tell if my wifi is enabled or not. When I click the wifi icon it does not give me a list of available networks. I'm using a wired connection to my router now, but without being physically plugged in it does not give any option to connect to a network. The closest I've gotten was a screen asking if/how I wanted to set up VPN

Comment: Ok, wait a second i will update my answer.

Comment: I do appreciate the help though! Thank you in advance

Comment: so it's stopping at "DKMS: install completed." It's been there for a while now, with an active process. Should I just leave it up there for the night?

Comment: If in the console you see YourUsername@laptopName :and you can type, then it is done. you can close the terminal and log out and log in.

Comment: unfortunately I can't see the username or the computer name. I'll paste everything that pops up after the second command is entered

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,301 kB of archives.

Comment: After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 196988 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace bcmwl-kernel-source 6.20.155.1+bdcom-0ubuntu0.0.1 (using .../bcmwl-kernel-source_6.20.155.1+bdcom-0ubuntu0.0.1_i386.deb) ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.

Comment: Unpacking replacement bcmwl-kernel-source ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.20.155.1+bdcom-0ubuntu0.0.1) ...
Loading new bcmwl-6.20.155.1+bdcom DKMS files...
Building only for 3.5.0-34-generic
Building for architecture i686
Building initial module for 3.5.0-34-generic
Done.

wl:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.5.0-34-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.

Comment: Ok, if you close terminal does it give you a warning or something? The process should not take that long, you should have finished it in like 5 min.

Comment: Yeah trying to close the terminal gives a warning that something is running and that closing it will stop it. I left it up and running for six hours-no dice.

Comment: Well apperantly it is stuck on something, don't really know what. All you can do now is press ctrl+C when you are in terminal, and then try to repeat the commands. Pretty sure you are going to get some errors, but let's try it. BTW this proces should have taken us 5 min, you decided to let your pc up for 6h, that wasn't necessary, probably by now we could have finished the problem. oh well...it was your choice...

Comment: yeah trying that over and over yielded similar results. Also now it pops up a message saying "E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?"

Comment: run this command in terminal: sudo fuser -cuk /var/lib/dpkg/lock; sudo rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/lock and then try again

Answer (score 0):

If you are plugged in, I would go download via the ubuntu web store, the appp called "Other Drivers" you may need to update your drivers. After you install and pdate, you need to restart your PC.